# gem normalize-scss not working with generator-jekyllized

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, normalize

I am using the [yeoman generator jekyllized](https://github.com/sondr3/generator-jekyllized). It sets up Jekyll with some useful add-ons. 
Now I'm trying to add [gem normalize-scss](https://github.com/JohnAlbin/normalize-scss).

Versions:

```
Sass 3.4.22 (Selective Steve)
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
gem 2.2.2
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'normalize-scss'
```

_config.yml:

```
# Extending Jekyll
gems:
 - jekyll-feed
 - jekyll-gist
 - jekyll-paginate
 - jekyll-sitemap
 - jekyll-seo-tag
 - jekyll-redirect-from
 - normalize-scss
```

style.scss:

```
@import "normalize";
```

The gem is installed locally but when I run `gulp`, I get the following error:

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
  src/assets/scss/style.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: normalize
   Parent style sheet: /.../src/assets/scss/style.scss
    on line 6 of src/assets/scss/style.scss
>> @import "normalize";
```

Why is it not found?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that  yeoman generator jekyllized use node-sass to "compile" scss files.
So it can't load ruby gems, I would suggest to install the npm version of normalize-scss.

```
npm install normalize-scss --save-dev
```

And then import the file that you need by path:

```
@import "<my_node_modules_path>/normalize-scss/<file_that_i_need>"
```